# Xcode Color Sets - No color picker option

Tags: ios, xcode, uicolor, color-picker

After upgrading to Xcode 10, I cant seem to find the Color Picker option as shown in the images. Anyone else facing the same issue/knows a way to solve it?

[Screenshot of my IDE's Color Asset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViegG.jpg)

[Screenshot of other people's IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMtvw.jpg)

Comment: can't find any difference between your's ide screenshot and others, please mark the place and define clearly what do you mean by "cant seem to find the color picker option" .

Comment: Apologies for not being clear, I've updated the pictures. Can't make it inline because I dont have enough rep points LOL

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I think it disappeared when I updated to Xcode 10.

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: @ElliotKoh did u get the answer for this.??

Comment: @veereshkumbar i have not gotten the answer :x ive just been following the workaround as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/53602206/10604184

Answer (score 7):

As a workaround you can use

`Edit` -> `Format` -> `Show colors`

After using your favorite color picker to select the color, you can drag and drop your color into the colored square at the center of the screen.

**Update**

The description above still works, but Apple has added access to the color panel at a more natural place again:

1. Click on the color
2. Click on the attributes inspector icon
3. Click on "Show Color Panel"

[image: Access Color Picker in Xcode]

Comment: funny how they find ways to give us a hard time. Why remove the color option on the right side? why not just double click the big square color to change it?

Answer (score 0):

It will only appear if you select square box of color display.
Not when you select the name of color set from the list.
Check this over here:

[image]